# getting error( java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index)

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc

**Storedprocedure**

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure
is
cursor c_emp is select * from employees;
r_name c_emp%rowtype;
begin
open c_emp;
loop
fetch c_emp into r_name;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r_name.EMP_NAME);
EXIT WHEN c_emp%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
close c_emp;
END;
```

**JDBC code**

```
stmt=conn.prepareCall("{call my_procedure}");

      stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
      while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println( rs.getString(1));
        }
```

It showing error like

**Error:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:371)
    at table.callstmt_storedprcd.main(callstmt_storedprcd.java:27)
```

I dont know why it is showing like this error.Please rectify my error.

Answer (score 1):

DBMS_OUTPUT is for displaying messages to a screen.  It isn't an OUT parameter.

Your procedure has no parameters.  Therefore this is going to break your program:

```
  stmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

Comment: then how to produce the results

Comment: then how to integreat  my Storedprocedure into JDBC